# Not able to select Button in custom table view cell in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tvos, custom-cell

I am working on a tvOS app in which custom table view cell is used, while showing data using labels is working perfectly fine but button selection is not working. is there any way to make button selection inside custom table view cell work in tvOS table view?

**code snippet:**

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
              MsgDetailsTableViewCell *cell;
              static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
             cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
              if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[MsgDetailsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
                }

             NSDictionary*dataDict = [self.qArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             NSString *followCountText =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Following",[[dataDict objectForKey:@"followCount"] stringValue]];
               if([[dataDict objectForKey:@"followCount"] integerValue]!=0)
                {
                    [cell.statusListBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openLikedList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];
                    cell.statusListBtn.tag=111;
                    cell.followCountLbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:95/255.0 blue:167/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                }
                else
                {
                    [cell.statusListBtn removeTarget:self action:@selector(openLikedList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];
                    cell.statusListBtn.tag=111;
                    cell.followCountLbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                }

                cell.followCountLbl.text=followCountText;
            return cell;
      }
```

In above code Selection of statusListBtn is not working.

Comment: please share code of `cellForRowAt` method

Comment: @Indrajeet edited question

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that only when `dataDict objectForKey:@"followCount"] integerValue]!=0` the button can perform the selector if so. you can try this

```
              MsgDetailsTableViewCell *cell;
              static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
             cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
              if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[MsgDetailsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
                    [cell.statusListBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openLikedList:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];
                    cell.statusListBtn.tag=111;
                }

             NSDictionary*dataDict = [self.qArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             NSString *followCountText =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Following",[[dataDict objectForKey:@"followCount"] stringValue]];
               if([[dataDict objectForKey:@"followCount"] integerValue]!=0)
                {
                    cell.statusListBtn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                    cell.followCountLbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:95/255.0 blue:167/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.statusListBtn.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    cell.followCountLbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                }

                cell.followCountLbl.text=followCountText;
            return cell;
```

If you want different event of button you can change `UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered` like `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`